# `fatal: Not a valid object name: 'master'` when creating a new branch in git

Tags: git

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorial/git-basics#!add) but I'm having trouble creating a new branch in a new repository. This is the error I'm getting:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git for beginners: The definitive practical guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/315911/git-for-beginners-the-definitive-practical-guide)

Comment: It's a pity the screenshot wasn't there at the beginning - you'd have gotten a lot more interest/help showing that a) you had tried the obvious b) were infact having problems creating a new branch on an empty repository (which is an entirely different problem than "how to create new files in git")

Comment: @AD7six Actually, I edit the question because I also know about to work with my own branch. I do not want to store in the Master branch

Comment: you have need to do more i.e, `git pull` and `git checkout master`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. To create a git repository locally, you have to be inside the project directory, then run `git init` command.
2. To add a file to git, you have to create a file, with some text editor for example. Then you have to add that file to git, then commit it locally.

   ```
   git add .

   git commit -m "A short description what you did to the file"
   ```

---

UPDATED based on the question update :

To create a git repository for a project

1. First you have to create a project directory.
2. Then from inside the directory, you have to issue `git init` to initialize a git repo for that project
3. By default, you will be in master branch, to create another branch, use `git branch <new branch name>`

To add new files to the created repository

1. Create new files like you create for a project.
2. Add those file to git using `git add .`
3. To commit the file, use `git commit -m "a Short description about the action you performed"`

Comment: sir i have to create that file on that master branch or anywhere else?

Comment: @NimitJoshi, By default, you will be master branch, It's up to you, to which branch you need to add the file.

Comment: How do i create a new branch? I do not need the master branch

Comment: @NimitJoshi, Don't you check any beginner's git tutorial?

Comment: I have checked, but i did not get the idea

Comment: @NimitJoshi : Use `git branch <your branch name>` to create a new branch.

Comment: Sir I used it , but it shows: fatal: Not a valid object name: 'master'

Comment: @NimitJoshi, How did you use?

Comment: I used a git branch Sample but it shows an error, you can check it out. i do not understand what is the problem. I did the same as you said. I made successfully a Sample directory. I can not make a new branch

Comment: I also created a new Readme.txt file and save it in the Sample directory and now when I am running git add Readme it shows that fatal: pathspec 'Readme' did not match any files

Comment: @NimitJoshi : You have to be inside the project directory to issue the command, I recommended delete all the thing you did upto now and start it from basic.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54424/discussion-between-nimit-joshi-and-abimaran-kugathasan).

Comment: If your project directory, where you do the git init, already has some files in it, then you have to `git add .` and `git commit` those changes in the master branch before git will let you create a new branch. That was the issue in my case. this might as well be the process for everytime to you do a git init even with an empty directory. but in my case, i was initialising an already full directory.

Answer (score 5):

1. Initialize a git repository (directory/folder on your computer)
   Navigate to this directory. Then use `git init`.
2. After you create files in this directory 
   `git add .`
3. Commit the changes 
   `git commit -m "your message"`

This might also help: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Basics-Getting-a-Git-Repository

Code recap:

```
git init
git add .
git commit -m "your message"
```

Comment: You said that after you create file in this directory. That's what i want. How do i create the file in master branch?

Comment: You want to create a file in this directory? You can add a file to the directory any way you would like. After you create this file and run "git add . " and "git commit -m "message" the file will be added to the git system.

Comment: Sir, would you please provide the code which adds some file in the master branch?

Answer (score 2):

You just have to use the command line :

```
git add #filename
git commit #filename
```

Comment: How do i create a new file let say from notepad into that location. If the file exist on any other location so how do i add that file?

Answer (score 1):

Do these

`git config --global user.name "YOUR NAME"`
.

`git config --global user.email "YOUR EMAIL ADDRESS"`

and then create a branch

Answer (score 0):

first you have to commit changes 
use  git commit -a
then use git branch again

Answer (score 0):

If your project directory, where you do the git init, already has some files in it, then you have to `git add .` and `git commit` those changes in the master branch before git will let you create a new branch. That was the issue in my case. This might as well be the stanadard process for everytime you do a git init even with an empty directory, but in my case, I was initialising an already full directory.